# Facet for Sitecore SXA search filter

Tags: solr, search-facet, sxa-search

The product item has a field "Property Type" which is a single line text

[image: Property type]

I want to create a facet so that I can use in the SXA search Checklist filter. I have added the field in the solr index like this

```
 <field fieldName="propertydetailpropertytype" storageType="YES" indexType="UN_TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" returnType="string" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
```

The showconfig.aspx shows the property type field

[image: field]

Then created a property type facet in the facets folder "Tenant/Site/Settings/Facets/" and set the Field Name to `propertydetailpropertytype`.

Then created the filter `Tenant/Site/Data/Search/Checklist Filter`.

I have rebuild the solr index but the Property type filter is not working. Its showing no result. This is the solr query result:

[image: solr result]

Am i missing any steps?

Comment: Did you try setting the facet to `propertydetailpropertytype_s` ?

Comment: @Gatogordo yeah it didn't work

Comment: Do I notice correctly that the query in solr also has no facets? So the issue is already there..  is the field in solr properly filled? I would try to get the query correct in the solr admin first.

Comment: @Gatogordo yeah there is no facet and I cannot find the field in the solr as well. I have already added the field in solr index (please check the code in the question asked). Can you suggest what else I need to do ?

Comment: Did you repopulate the schema?

Comment: @Gatogordo should i repopulate through the control panel?

Comment: Yes - repopulate and reindex. And make sure you are using the SXA indexes..

Comment: @Gatogordo yeah i tried that and it still didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122451/discussion-between-owais-ahmed-and-gatogordo).